# How to get the index number of the posts?

Tags: functions, shortcode

I was trying to get the index number of the posts which belong to a specific category. I tried to create a shortcode to achieve that but no luck, it returns "1" for all posts.

```
// Get the current post index number by [manset_post_index]
function manset_post_index() {
$manset_posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'              => 'post',
            'post_status'            => 'publish',
            'category_name'          => 'manset',
            'update_post_term_cache' => false,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'cache_results'          => false,
        ) );

    if ( $manset_posts->have_posts() ) : $manset_posts->the_post();
        $thenumber = $manset_posts->current_post + 1;
    endif;
   return $thenumber;
   }
add_shortcode( 'manset_post_index', 'manset_post_index' );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I'm using this shortcode [mycategory_post_index] in a layer of Post Based Revslider. The frontend result should be like "3" which means: the 3rd (3rd post in descending order) post in that specific category.

The solution over Revslider API:

By the way, there is another solution based on Revslider API, someone might need it, so I am sharing for good.
This goes to rev slider custom js console.

```
    var api = revapi6,
    numberText;

api.one('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

    numberText = api.find('.slide-status-numbers').text('1');

    api.on('revolution.slide.onbeforeswap', function(e, data) {

        numberText.text((data.nextslide.index() + 1));

    });

});
```

then you add "slide-status-numbers" class name into your layer attributes.

Comment: If you want to know the number  of posts returned by WP_Query, use `$manset_posts->found_posts`. See the codex for more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/.

Comment: thanks @shanebp but I did that part (number of posts in a specific category), I want to get the post index number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the index numbers for the posts array returned by WP_Query ?

Try this:

```
if ( $manset_posts->have_posts() ) {
     foreach( $manset_posts->posts as $key => $value ) {
          // $key is the index number for each post
     }
}
```

Comment: It looks brilliant. Is there any trick to use it in my shortcode, like do I need to return it or do I need to echo it, do I need to reset the query with wp_reset_query, etc.

Comment: If the answer was helpful - please mark it as accepted.  Typically, shortcode output is returned.  And resetting the query is a good idea.

Comment: I fixed my issue with REVSLIDER API but many thanks for the answer. I marked it as accepted. By the way, I'll try to replace the solution and share the results here.